# Handling `const float *` parameters in c++ when generating Java proxy classes through SWIG?

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm trying to wrap a c++ project in Java using SWIG v4 but I'm having trouble dealing with some of the method parameters. Within the project, `const float *` is used fairly frequently as an input parameter type. This pointer type is used to point to the data from a `std::vector<float>` object (i.e., the result of calling `std::vector::data`).

Here is an example c++ header file, `example.h`, which provides a simplified version of the c++ code I'm working with:

```
#include <vector>

namespace example {

struct Index {
    int dimension;
    int numVectors;
    std::vector<float> vectors;

    explicit Index(long d = 0):
        dimension(d),
        numVectors(0) {}

    void add (int n, const float *x) {
        vectors.insert(vectors.end(), x, x + n * dimension);
        numVectors += n;
    }
};

}
```

When the Java proxy classes are generated by SWIG, I would like to have a way of working with the methods that use this pointer input type that is natural to Java. My strategy thus far has been to use the `std_vector.i` file to define a `FloatVector` template for `std::vector<float>`, and then to provide several typemaps that allow this `FloatVector` proxy class to be used on the Java side and accepted as input when passed through the JNI wrapper to the native side. However, I have been unable to author the correct typemaps to allow me to achieve my desired outcome.

I'm looking for the best way to deal with `const float *` input parameters in c++ methods expecting `std::vector<float>::data` as arguments when trying to generate Java proxy classes and JNI wrappers.